# Is this algorithm for calculating the variance correct?

Tags: c++, math

I have the following numbers in `v_samples` (1.4, 2.21, 4.21, 2.1, 5.1)

I get deviance = 2.45122

but when I checked on some deviance calculator [websites](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=variance%20calculator&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a). they all gave me different answers.

```
double variance(){
        double variance =0 ;
        double average = mean();
        double size = v_samples.size();
        for (size_t i = 0, max = size; i != max; ++i){
            variance += (v_samples[i]-average) * (v_samples[i]-average) / size;
        }
        return variance;
    }
```

edit: variance not deviance

edit: mean() returns 2.804

edit: mean now returns the correct value 3.004

the sample variance now returns 1.97362. is this correct

Comment: It's correct if all samples are weighted equally.

Comment: You just asked this question...

Comment: It's just due to rounding errors I'd assume.  Correct answer is 2.46703

Comment: Are you trying to calculate deviance or variance? They are two different things...

Comment: what number does mean() return?

Comment: @yi_H mean returns 2.804

Comment: Do you want a [sample variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Estimating_the_variance) or population variance?

Comment: @sarnold sample variance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sum of

```
1.4, 2.21, 4.21, 2.1, 5.1
```

is **15.02**  and Mean is **3.004**

if you are getting the mean to be **2.804**.

```
 2.804 * 5 = 14.02
```

**15.02** and **14.02** are off by 1. You have an off by one error somewhere :)

Comment: yes the mean was a wrong now ive fixed it. i am not getting 1.97362 for variance (sample variance) is this correct?

Comment: What value are you getting for variance. I get 1.973624 with your exact same function if mean is 3.004

Answer (score 1):

It should work, so you have a problem in `mean()`.

Comment: yes the problem was in the mean. I've eddited my original post. please have a look

Comment: yes and I figured it out.. please upvote :/

Answer (score 1):

The confusion in your on-line sources is almost certainly between the "sample variance" and the "bias-corrected sample variance".  The latter needs `size-1` in the denominator instead of `size`.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Variance.html